Mobaxterm: ssh-browser asks for unknown password
I am connecting to a server where I can connect using ssh and sftp without any trouble from the mobaxterm local session command line. I dont need a password any more because I have the ssh-keys set up for both of them.
When I connect using the start new session feature, ssh works fine. I want to start the ssh-browser, but that asks for a password. I try the password that I know works for the server, and that fails.
Dialog box
How can I get around this? I tried setting the private key for sftp etc, no luck.

You’re going to need to provide the password. I suspect ssh-browser doesn’t support key authentication.
